# How do I have a trait field in a struct?

Tags: enums, rust, traits

I have some code that I want to turn into a crate. But it includes a structure that contains a field that I want to be provided by the user of the crate. But I need functionality from that field, so I want to specify it as a trait.

```
pub trait RoleTrait {
    fn owner<T: RoleTrait>() -> T;
    fn order<T: RoleTrait>(&self) -> usize;
}

pub struct RequestInfo<Role: RoleTrait + PartialEq> {
    role: Option<Role>,
    name: String,
}

impl<Role: RoleTrait> RequestInfo<Role>
where
    Role: std::cmp::PartialEq,
{
    fn name(&self) -> String {
        self.name.to_string()
    }

    fn role(&self) -> &Option<Role> {
        &self.role
    }

    fn is_owner(&self) -> bool {
        if let Some(role) = self.role {
            role == Role::owner()
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
    fn order(&self) -> usize {
        if let Some(role) = self.role {
            role.order() + 1
        } else {
            0
        }
    }

    fn from(name: String) -> RequestInfo<Role> {
        RequestInfo::<Role> {
            role: None,
            name: name,
        }
    }

    fn with_role(name: String, role: Role) -> RequestInfo<Role> {
        RequestInfo::<Role> {
            role: Some(role),
            name: name,
        }
    }
}
```

With two implementations of `RoleTrait`:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub enum CourseRole {
    Professor,
    Marker,
    Student,
}

impl RoleTrait for CourseRole {
    fn owner<T: RoleTrait>() -> T {
        CourseRole::Professor
    }

    fn order<T: RoleTrait>(&self) -> usize {
        if *self == CourseRole::Professor {
            0
        } else {
            1
        }
    }
}

#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub enum BlogRole {
    Owner,
    Blogger,
}

impl RoleTrait for BlogRole {
    fn owner<T: RoleTrait>() -> T {
        BlogRole::Owner
    }

    fn order<T: RoleTrait>(&self) -> usize {
        if *self == BlogRole::Owner {
            0
        } else {
            1
        }
    }
}
```

I get 3 errors with this.

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:28:18
   |
28 |             role.order() + 1
   |                  ^^^^^ cannot infer type for `T`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:55:9
   |
54 |     fn owner<T: RoleTrait>() -> T {
   |                                 - expected `T` because of return type
55 |         CourseRole::Professor
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found enum `CourseRole`
   |
   = note: expected type `T`
              found type `CourseRole`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:72:9
   |
71 |     fn owner<T: RoleTrait>() -> T {
   |                                 - expected `T` because of return type
72 |         BlogRole::Owner
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found enum `BlogRole`
   |
   = note: expected type `T`
              found type `BlogRole`
```

(and the second error repeated for the other enum)

Frankly, I'm surprised (and pleased!) that some of my code is valid (like the references to `owner` in the trait). I had a lot more errors when I started writing this question, but I can't figure out these remaining ones since `T` looks so clear and `rustc` seems to have already figured out harder things. In the last 2 errors, it's almost like it doesn't realize that there is an implementation of the trait for the enum because it's in the middle of defining that implementation (but it obviously understands that in other places).

Comment: You can fix the first problem by adding type information, like `role.order::<Role>()`. The second/third problem may be originating from your decision to use type parameters instead of [associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#specifying-placeholder-types-in-trait-definitions-with-associated-types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something feels a little "off" with this trait:

```
pub trait RoleTrait {
    fn owner<T: RoleTrait>() -> T;
    fn order<T: RoleTrait>(&self) -> usize;
}
```

The `owner` method doesn't have a receiver (e.g. `self`), so it seems unnecessary to introduce a new type parameter; `Self` will do the same thing.

In `order`, having a separate `T` is not *exactly* the same thing as just using `Self` - it allows `T` and `Self` to be a completely different implementations of `RoleTrait`. But this feels like quite a strange and unusual requirement, especially since `T` doesn't appear in the method signature.

Your code can be fixed quite simply by following the more typical pattern:

```
pub trait RoleTrait {
    fn owner() -> Self;
    fn order(&self) -> usize;
}
```

---

This small change leads to all the type errors being resolved, and just leaving a couple of small borrow errors ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d260b28a3c6c8255d6a8263f827c54e1)), which can be quite easily addressed ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dad83bdf96dd2f41ecc15535e6933f43)).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. As T and Self could be different, it's now clear why it couldn't infer the correct type.